# Cloudflare error 1015 you are are being rate limited

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages

We are using Cloudflare on our website. We have a page where users can search for products on our website. Along with the products we display product images on that page.
One product has a minimum of 10 images and users can see 200 products at one time on that page.
On that page we are getting Cloud flare error: 1015 You are being rated limited. This error blocks access to the website for that IP for 5 minutes.
We do not have any rate limit rule setup in Cloudflare.

Is there any default rate limit being applied to our website?
Do we need to setup a rule for a higher threshold?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/limits/#burst-rate